# Custom iOS Floating Button

Tags: ios, floating-action-button, assistive

I've been looking around on the internet and there doesn't seem to be much in the way of conversation (or I'm asking the wrong question - I'm new at Objective-C and iOS both) about creating a custom Assistive Touch-like button in iOS.

I would like to access my app from a launcher application and then float a button that would let me go back into said launcher from anywhere in my app. The floating Assistive Touch button scheme seems perfect - has anyone made something like that?

[EDIT]

In response to the meaningful questions - I wasn't clear enough (again, apologies - inexperienced here).

I have three apps: App Gatherer, App Target 01, App Target 02.

App Gatherer will be able to launch multiple apps via URL. Once it does that, and the new app opens, I'm wondering if I can have a floating button that can be moved around and clicked seperate from the UI of the Target App like the Assistive Touch button. The purpose of the floating button is to get me back out of any Target Apps - it's totally separate - to the Gatherer App.

I don't have any implementation - I'm just trying to map it out and see if it's even possible. Am I in the wrong place to ask that?

Comment: So is your question really asking how to have a button in your app that is available from any screen in your app?

Comment: Just create a button and add it directly to the `window`.

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by launcher? There's just the desktop and you can't quit an iOS app therefore you can't use a button to return to the desktop. An app can be launched (via a URL) from another app, is that what you are talking about? Or something else. Your question about a button is premature, you first need to step back and evaluate if the whole launching/returning functionality you want is even possible, forget about a button.

Comment: If you really want to create a button that is available from everywhere and always stays on the screen no matter which app the user is in, then forget about it. Neither will that be possible to create, nor will Apple allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u open a app using url from AppGatherer. Then in the Target app there is only 1 way of going back to appgatherer and that is using a url again but this time opening AppGatherer. So the custom floating button will have to be implemented inside the AppTarget and when the person clicks that button AppGatherer is opened via URL Scheme. There is no other way around. You cant have a floating universal button. You will have to implement the floating button inside every AppTarget application seperately. Plus it goes without saying that button will have to be implemented in every seperate view you have within the AppTargt application.

And in order to make a floating button you will need to keep above all other views plus handle its dragging within the onDrag methods and etc.